# Правильна ли пунктуация в предложении "Я всё куплю, я говорю!"?

Tags: пунктуация

Верна ли пунктуация в предложении:

> Я всё куплю, я говорю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это один из возможных вариантов (а подходит ли он в данном случае, трудно утверждать с уверенностью в отсутствие контекста).

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Немедленно! Приказываю!.. ― И он выругался внезапно, как не ругался никогда в ее присутствии. ― **Уходи, я говорю!** ― Я помогу… Я с тобой, лейтенант… Она придвигалась к нему на коленях, она пристально смотрела, не узнавая его, всегда сдержанного, городского лейтенанта, а обе руки ее держали снаряд, прижав к груди. [Юрий Бондарев. Горячий снег (1969)]

Answer (score 1):

Предложение нужно редактировать, оно построено некорректно:

Например: *Я же говорю, я всё куплю*.

Comment: Ну, я бы сказал, стилистически неудачно, но некорректно ?

Comment: Здесь стилистическая некорректность близка к грамматической. В заданном варианте вводное предложение "я говорю", формально нельзя отличить от основного, а это нужно сделать хотя бы как-то. А предложенную запись можно прочитать с перечислительной интонацией и ничего не понять.